# Run multiple microservices in single tab

Tags: django, python-3.x, localhost, microservices

I have 10 microservices in django. I am running all microservices in different tab in terminal on localhost.So I want to run all microservices in single tab. I don't want to open multiple tab. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you are on windows platform use batch file to run multiple microservices on just one click.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using commands like below for every service you have.

```
python3 service.py
```

You can use nohup to execute commands to start services as background processes.

Here the usage of nohup :

```
$ nohup command-name &
$ exit
```

Another usage in your case to see the logs easily :

```
$ nohup python3 service.py > output.log &
$ exit
```

Comment: I am running like python3 manage.py runserver {port}. All microserivce having own virtual environment. So how can we assign virtual environment with this command ?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try activating venv and then execute commands with nohup.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use docker for micro services.
I have currently deployed my django application in production environment using docker I can manage them using docker-compose.
Alternatively you can create shell script file for each micro service where you can define there own environment settings.